# Error in Iconify library: AttributeError - '_IconEngine' object has no attribute '_pixmapGenerators'

Tags: python, pyside6

I'm encountering an issue with the Iconify library in my Python code, and I could use some help in understanding and resolving the problem. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
            # Fallback to Breathe animation for spinning effect
            icon_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(base_path, "extra_ressource", "iconify_icone"))
            ico.path.addIconDirectory(icon_dir)
    
            self.clockwiseSpinningAnim_1 = ico.anim.Spin(direction=ico.anim.Spin.Directions.ANTI_CLOCKWISE, rpm=15)
            icon_path = os.path.join(icon_dir, "pushButton_earth_file.svg")
    
            icon = ico.Icon(icon_path, anim=self.clockwiseSpinningAnim_1)
            icon.setAsButtonIcon(self.ui.pushButton_earth_points)
            self.ui.pushButton_earth_points.setIconSize(QSize(463, 463))
            threading.Thread(self.clockwiseSpinningAnim_1.start()).start()
    
            self.clockwiseSpinningAnim_2 = ico.anim.Spin(direction=ico.anim.Spin.Directions.CLOCKWISE, rpm=5)
            icon_path = os.path.join(icon_dir, "pushButton_earth_points.svg")
    
            icon = ico.Icon(icon_path, anim=self.clockwiseSpinningAnim_2)
            icon.setAsButtonIcon(self.ui.pushButton_earth_file)
            self.ui.pushButton_earth_file.setIconSize(QSize(440, 440))
            threading.Thread(self.clockwiseSpinningAnim_2.start()).start()
```

```
core.py of iconify library:

"""
The primary objects for interfacing with iconify
"""

from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, MutableMapping, Optional, Tuple

from iconify.anim import GlobalTick
from iconify.path import findIcon
from iconify.qt import QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg

if TYPE_CHECKING:
from iconify.anim import BaseAnimation
from iconify.qt import QtWidgets
PixmapCacheKey = Tuple\[Optional\[str\], QtCore.QSize, str, int, int\]

class Icon(QtGui.QIcon):
"""
The Iconify Icon which renders an svg image
using the provided color & anim.
"""

    def __new__(
        cls,
        path,  # type: str
        color=None,  # type: Optional[QtGui.QColor]
        anim=None  # type: Optional[BaseAnimation]
    ):
        # type: (...) -> QtGui.QIcon
        """
        Return a QtGui.QIcon with extra convenience methods patched onto it.
    
        Patching a QIcon, rather than subclassing it, is required for the
        object to work correctly with Qt's model / view framework.
    
        Parameters
        ----------
        path : str
        color : Optional[QtGui.QColor]
        anim : Optional[BaseAnimation]
    
        Returns
        -------
        QtGui.QIcon
        """
        iconEngine = _IconEngine(path, color=color, anim=anim)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon(iconEngine)
    
        def _setAsButtonIcon(button):
            # type: (QtWidgets.QAbstractButton) -> None
            button.setIcon(icon)
            if iconEngine.animCount() > 1:
                GlobalTick.timeout.connect(button.update)
            else:
                if anim is not None:
                    anim.tick.connect(button.update)
    
        icon.setAsButtonIcon = _setAsButtonIcon
        icon.addState = iconEngine.addState
        icon.pixmapGenerator = iconEngine.pixmapGenerator
        icon.color = iconEngine.color
        icon.anim = iconEngine.anim
        icon.animCount = iconEngine.animCount
        return icon

class \_IconEngine(QtGui.QIconEngine):
"""
A QIconEngine which uses a PixmapGenerator for it's work.
"""

    def __init__(self, path, color=None, anim=None):
        # type: (str, Optional[QtGui.QColor], Optional[BaseAnimation]) -> None
        super(_IconEngine, self).__init__()
        self._defaultGenerator = PixmapGenerator(path, color=color, anim=anim)
        self._pixmapGenerators = {(QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off):
                                  self._defaultGenerator}
    
    def __del__(self):
        # type: () -> None
        """
        Re-implemented to avoid this object being
        garbage collected unnecessarily.
        """
    
    def addState(
        self,
        path,  # type: str
        color=None,  # type: Optional[QtGui.QColor]
        anim=None,  # type: Optional[BaseAnimation]
        mode=QtGui.QIcon.Normal,  # type: QtGui.QIcon.Mode
        state=QtGui.QIcon.Off  # type: QtGui.QIcon.State
    ):
        # type: (...) -> None
        """
        Use the provided path, color and animation when an icon is requested
        for the identified mode and state.
    
        Parameters
        ----------
        path : str
        color : Optional[QtGui.QColor]
        anim : Optional[BaseAnimation]
        mode : QtGui.QIcon.Mode
        state : QtGui.QIcon.Stat
        """
        color = color or self.color()
        anim = anim or self.anim()
        generator = PixmapGenerator(path, color=color, anim=anim)
        self._pixmapGenerators[(mode, state)] = generator
    
    def pixmapGenerator(self, mode=QtGui.QIcon.Normal, state=QtGui.QIcon.Off):
        # type: (QtGui.QIcon.Mode, QtGui.QIcon.State) -> PixmapGenerator
        """
        Return the PixmapGenerator to use for the provided mode & state.
    
        If no PixmapGenerator has been defined for the provided mode & state
        combination, the PixmapGenerator created in the constructor is used.
    
        Parameters
        ----------
        mode : QtGui.QIcon.Mode
        state : QtGui.QIcon.State
    
        Returns
        -------
        PixmapGenerator
        """
        return self._pixmapGenerators.get(
            (mode, state),
            self._defaultGenerator,
        )
    
    def anim(
        self,
        mode=QtGui.QIcon.Normal,  # type: QtGui.QIcon.Mode
        state=QtGui.QIcon.Off,  # type: QtGui.QIcon.State
    ):
        # type: (...) -> Optional[BaseAnimation]
        """
        Return the animation used for the provided mode & state.
    
        Parameters
        ----------
        mode : QtGui.QIcon.Mode
        state : QtGui.QIcon.State
    
        Returns
        -------
        Optional[BaseAnimation]
        """
        return self.pixmapGenerator(mode=mode, state=state).anim()
    
    def animCount(self):
        # type: () -> int
        """
        Return the number of animations that are associated with the available
        states of this icon engine.
    
        Returns
        -------
        int
        """
        animCount = 0
        for pixmapGenerator in self._pixmapGenerators.values():
            if pixmapGenerator.anim() is not None:
                animCount += 1
        return animCount
    
    def color(
        self,
        mode=QtGui.QIcon.Normal,  # type: QtGui.QIcon.Mode
        state=QtGui.QIcon.Off,  # type: QtGui.QIcon.State
    ):
        # type: (...) -> Optional[QtGui.QColor]
        """
        Return the color used for the provided mode & state.
    
        Parameters
        ----------
        mode : QtGui.QIcon.Mode
        state : QtGui.QIcon.State
    
        Returns
        -------
        Optional[BaseAnimation]
        """
        return self.pixmapGenerator(mode=mode, state=state).color()
    
    def pixmap(
        self,
        size,  # type: QtCore.QSize
        mode,  # type: QtGui.QIcon.Mode
        state,  # type: QtGui.QIcon.State
    ):
        # type: (...) -> QtGui.QPixmap
        """
        Return a QPixmap to use for the identified mode & state, rendered at
        the provided size.
    
        Parameters
        ----------
        size : QtCore.QSize
        mode : QtGui.QIcon.Mode
        state : QtGui.QIcon.State
    
        Returns
        -------
        QtGui.QPixmap
        """
        return self.pixmapGenerator(mode=mode, state=state).pixmap(size)
    
    def paint(
        self,
        painter,  # type: QtCore.QPainter
        rect,  # type: QtCore.QRect
        mode,  # type: QtGui.QIcon.Mode
        state,  # type: QtGui.QIcon.State
    ):
        # type: (...) -> None
        painter.drawPixmap(
            rect.topLeft(), self.pixmap(rect.size(), mode, state)
        )

class PixmapGenerator(QtCore.QObject):
"""
Responsible for rendering the svg image and applying the color and
transform from the animation during the process.

    It's backed by a cache to ensure that redundant rendering does not happen.
    """
    
    _pixmapCache = {}  # type: MutableMapping[PixmapCacheKey, QtGui.QPixmap]
    
    def __init__(
        self,
        path,  # type: str
        color=None,  # type: Optional[QtGui.QColor]
        anim=None,  # type: Optional[BaseAnimation]
        parent=None,  # type: Optional[QtCore.QObject]
    ):
        # type: (...) -> None
        super(PixmapGenerator, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self._path = findIcon(path)
        self._color = color  # type: Optional[QtGui.QColor]
        self._anim = anim  # type: Optional[BaseAnimation]
    
        self._renderer = QtSvg.QSvgRenderer(self._path)
    
    def path(self):
        # type: () -> str
        """
        Return the path to the image used by this PixmapGenerator.
    
        Returns
        -------
        str
        """
        return self._path
    
    def color(self):
        # type: () -> Optional[QtGui.QColor]
        """
        Return the color used by this PixmapGenerator.
    
        Returns
        -------
        Optional[QtGui.QColor]
        """
        return self._color
    
    def anim(self):
        # type: () -> Optional[BaseAnimation]
        """
        Return the animation used by this PixmapGenerator.
    
        Returns
        -------
        Optional[BaseAnimation]
        """
        return self._anim
    
    def pixmap(self, size):
        # type: (QtCore.QSize) -> QtGui.QPixmap
        """
        Render the svg file to a QPixmap, applying the color override and the
        animation transform if applicable.
    
        Parameters
        ----------
        size : QtCore.QSize
    
        Returns
        -------
        QtGui.QPixmap
        """
        color = self._color.rgb() if self._color else -1
    
        if self._anim is not None:
            key = (
                self._path, size, str(self._anim.__class__),
                self._anim.frame(), color
            )  # type: PixmapCacheKey
        else:
            key = (self._path, size, "", 0, color)
    
        if key in self._pixmapCache:
            return self._pixmapCache[key]
    
        image = QtGui.QImage(
            size,
            QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied,
        )
        image.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
    
        # Use the QSvgRenderer to draw the image
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(image)
    
        if self._anim:
            # Rotate the painter's co-ordinate space so
            # the image is correctly positioned.
            xfm = self._anim.transform(size)
            painter.setTransform(xfm)
    
        self._renderer.render(painter)
        painter.end()
    
        if self._color is not None:
            # Use the alpha channel on a solid colour image
            colorImage = QtGui.QImage(
                size,
                QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied,
            )
            colorImage.fill(QtGui.QColor(self._color))
            try:
                colorImage.setAlphaChannel(image.alphaChannel())
            except AttributeError:
                if image.hasAlphaChannel():
                    colorImage.setAlphaChannel(image)
    
            image = colorImage
    
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self._pixmapCache[key] = pixmap
        return pixmap
```

When I run this code, I encounter the following error:

File "C:\python\MOA-Toolkits_Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\iconify\core.py", line 211, in pixmap
return self.pixmapGenerator(mode=mode, state=state).pixmap(size)
File "C:\python\MOA-Toolkits_Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\iconify\core.py", line 129, in pixmapGenerator
return self._pixmapGenerators.get(
AttributeError: '_IconEngine' object has no attribute '_pixmapGenerators'. Did you mean: 'pixmapGenerator'?

It seems to be related to the Iconify library's internals. I'm using version 0.0.103 of the library. Has anyone encountered this issue before, and if so, how did you resolve it? Are there any known workarounds or updates that address this problem?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!